# tex and rails snippets do not expand in ultisnips?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I am new to using plugins with Vim. I mostly work with rails, ruby, latex and html code. I have already installed [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) plugins using pathogen. I would like corresponding snippets files to be available while I work with these file types. I have tried `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails` which works perfectly, and would like to place `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails.ruby.latex.html` in `ftplugin/rails.vim` as ultisnips documentation mentions

> The UltiSnipsAddFiletypes command allows for explicit merging of other snippet filetypes for the current buffer. For example, if you edit a .rst file but also want the Lua snippets to be available you can issue the command >

```
   :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rst.lua
```

> using the dotted filetype syntax. Order is important, the first filetype in this list will be the one used for UltiSnipsEdit and the list is
>   ordered by evaluation priority. Consequently, you might add this to your
>   `ftplugin/rails.vim` >

```
   :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails.ruby
```

**The problem is that I cannot find any file named `rails.vim`.**
**Update:**
Since only some snippets are expanding while other are not I think the problem is with how I have setup plugins on my system. Here is how `vim` and `vimrc` have been setup:

```
call pathogen#infect()
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips
set nocompatible
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsListSnippets="<s-tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<s-j>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-k>"
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["vim-snippets", "Ultisnips"]
```

`.vim/bundle` folder contains the cloned git repos [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).

I have also symlinked `ftdetect` as suggested in the installation section of ultisnips documentation. I am using vim 7.4. I would be grateful to the community for their help.

Answer (score 1):

`UltiSnipsAddFiletypes` is not creating any files. It just informs UltiSnips that when you edit for example a `rails` file, you also want snippets from file type `html` and/or `ruby` and/or `javascript` and so on.

If you run command `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails.ruby.html.javascript` then it's important what file type is first (`rails` in this example) - this will be used in `UltiSnipsEdit` command as a file type.

If you can't find any file named `rails.vim`, that's because UltiSnips creates and uses files with `.snippets` file extension - check out what's inside [UltiSnip folder of vim-snippets plugin](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/tree/master/UltiSnips)

**Update after OP edit**

Since you're using Pathogen, you don't need line:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips
```

as well as that `ftdetect` symlink.

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["vim-snippets", "Ultisnips"]
```

This may be the problem. As described in `:h UltiSnips-snippet-search-path`, this variable is used for subfolders that are contained in direcotries in `runtimepath`, so `vim-snippets` is actually a folder in `runtimepath` that contains `snippets` and `UltiSnips` subfolders which have `snippet` files. I think that you can remove that line, as it defaults to `["UltiSnips"]` (please also note the capital `S` letter).

Comment: I am actually quite confused the way ultisnips is behaving at the moment, html snippets are expanding without any problem, others (latex, rails) do not expand at all.

Comment: I have updated the vimrc file to reflect your suggestions, but tex snippets are not expanding, is there any command that can be run to test what is causing the problem

Comment: Is file type for LaTeX files `tex` or `latex`? If `tex`, than you wrote originally that you added 4 file types to `ftplugin/rails.vim` that contains `latex`, not `tex`

Comment: latex files have .tex extension, the corresponding snippets are in tex.snippets. I wrote that I wanted to add but actually did not find the suggested file `ftplugin/rails.vim`

Comment: So you manually insert this command every time? -> `:UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails.ruby.latex.html` - which has `latex`, not `tex`. You can add that in `~/.vim/ftplugin/rails.vim` - create if doesn't exist

Comment: This results in error `Error detected while processing ftdetect/rails.vim Not an editor command`

Comment: My mistake, `help` was misleading here. This should be `normal :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes rails.ruby.tex.html`